# How can I send PUT request on Node Express

Tags: firebase, express

I want to send a PUT request to server.

I tried on the code on localhost.
POST request is OK but PUT request doesn't work.

```js
app.put('/test/:id', (req, res) => {
    console.log("I am test");
    res.header('Content-Type', 'application/json; charset=utf-8');
    res.status(201).send({result: "ok"});
});

app.post('/test/:id', (req, res) => {
    console.log("I am test");
    res.header('Content-Type', 'application/json; charset=utf-8');
    res.status(201).send({result: "ok"});
});
```

Here is my postman output.

[image]

I expect PUT request response same as POST request.

Sorry about my English.  I'm Japanese.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, although I'm not sure why your code wouldn't do the same thing:

```
app.route('/test/:id').put((req, res) => {
        console.log("I am test");
        res.header('Content-Type', 'application/json; charset=utf-8');
        res.status(201).send({result: "ok"});
    }).post((req, res) => {
        console.log("I am test");
        res.header('Content-Type', 'application/json; charset=utf-8');
        res.status(201).send({result: "ok"});
});
```

Comment: I tried , but it is same response.I think something wrong with cors . I'll check.

Comment: I deployed the functions to firebase, then error disappear. I don't know why, but I'll move on. Thank you.